# Incompatible type: Inventory Fragment and Context

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    holder.ivMore.setOnClickListener {
        if (context is InventoryFragment){
            context.updateRecordDialog(item)
        }
    }
```

How do I convert the fragment to context in my ItemAdapter.kt? Thank you

Comment: You can't. `Fragment` is not a `Context`

Comment: @ArpitShukla what can I do to fix this then?

Comment: One way is to send this event back to the fragment containing the recycler view

Comment: You can consider to use a callback or listener instead, so those `setOnClickListener()` would invoke the callback

Comment: I think it would be better to use ViewModel.ViewModel is the best way to communicate between fragments.